# Mobile phone internet USB tethering very slow

Tags: internet, usb-tethering

I have Samsung Galaxy S6 edge+. My download speeds on my phone is 33+ MB/s with my mobile carrier. I connect the phone to my PC and use the internet from the phone with USB tethering enabled. The download speed is now 30KB/s on my computer but still 33MB/s on my phone.

I have tried changing/updating the USB tether driver via Device manager to Microsoft:

- Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing Device, and
- Remote NDIS Compatible Device

but neither helped.

Why has the speed been very limited via USB tethering, and how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Mobile network carrier often have transparent gateways installed all mobile network traffic have to pass. Such gateways are able to "detect" (smart guessing) if traffic comes from the Smartphone or a tethered PC.

Depending on the data plan contract, tethering may be prohibited and in such a case the carrier can just forcefully slow down the tethered connection.

As only the tethered connections are slowed down you can end up in a situation where identical downloads get a totally different download speed.